# OpenVPN --allow-pull-fqdn Not Working

Tags: dns, openvpn

Below are the base settings of the client.ovpn file, being run on Windows 10 via OpenVPN GUI.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <vpn_address> <vpn_port>
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 1
```

I am attempting to configure this client so that only one, single address is routed over the VPN.

Doing this via IP address works like a charm:

[CASE 1]

```
route-nopull
route 192.168.1.123 255.255.255.255
```

However, changing the settings to:

[CASE 2]

```
route-nopull
allow-pull-fqdn
route user2426679.service 255.255.255.255
```

Fails with:

```
Thu Sep 27 14:28:33 2018 RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: user2426679.service: (No such host is known. )
Thu Sep 27 14:28:33 2018 OpenVPN ROUTE: failed to parse/resolve route for host/network: user2426679.service
```

The curious part is that I can connect to `user2426679.service` just fine over the VPN with these settings:

[CASE 3]

```
route-nopull
allow-pull-fqdn
route user2426679.service 255.255.255.255
dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1
redirect-gateway def1
```

*Note:* I still get the error message/log entry of `Cannot resolve host address ...` and `failed to parse ...`

*But,* when I actually hit `user2426679.service` in my application, it is successful.

What gives?  For some reason, the config load of `route user2426679.service 255.255.255.255` does not succeed in making the DNS request, but the DNS is resolved without problem *over the same VPN connection* later on (when using VPN for all DNS requests in [CASE 3], which is not the desired scenario of [CASE 2], which doesn't work at all).

The [man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage) says that `allow-pull-fqdn` will "Allow client to pull DNS names from server" for `route`, but this does not appear to be happening.

Comment: Late to comment here. We discovered that OpenVPN 3.x no longer supports `allow-pull-fqdn` and will raise a parse-related error when `route` is given a hostname. Both of these features do work on OpenVPN 2.x.